# How do I repeatedly call a method when my iOS 4 app is in the background?

Tags: loops, audio, ios4, background, multitasking

I am writing an app for iOS 4 that needs to play a sound (or vibrate) at regular (user-specified) intervals when in the background. I do not want to use local notifications because there is no need to have a clickable alert appear.

This code (from Apple's docs) gets triggered when my app switches to the background:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Do the work associated with the task.
    NSLog(@"I am now in the background");

    // Here I need something like this:
    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```

The `[self performSelector: ...]` line gets executed when the app is switched to the background, but the `myMethod` method is not called until the app is switched back to the foreground (not in 5 seconds, as set at the `afterDelay:` parameter). So, how can I cause the method to be called while the app is still in the background?

Comment: Would you kindly tell that for how much time your app will remain in the background ? i read that its 10 mins maximum.. is it right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Scheduling local notifications can do what I need.

It is better to use local notifications along with `UIApplication cancelAllLocalNotifications` to clear out existing notifications which the user has not dismissed. Perfect! Plus, the user gets the added benefit if a popup message to let them know what the sound (or vibrate) was for.